# How to run mysql prompt in windows powershell ISE?

Tags: windows, mysql, powershell

I want to use PowerShell ISE tab to be able to connect mysql client and tun sql statements, however as soon as I connect to client using following command -

```
>mysql.exe --defaults-file=<abc.xnf> --datadir=<xyz>
```

mysql prompt doesn't appear instead console behaves as a continuous process running. Does anyone know how can get mysql prompt ?

Comment: Well, isn't it bad without even explaining the reason question is down voted. I've a problem so I asked question if someone feels question is naive, at least care to answer before down vote so that my problem is resolved :(

Comment: You are probably down voted because someone is trying to get a hat. Look at how many -1 questions there are.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the ISE is not a full-on console host, and does not handle interactive console applications properly. If you try to run a built-in interactive console app, like netsh.exe, you'll get an error like this:

```
Cannot start "netsh". Interactive console applications are not supported. 
To run the application, use the Start-Process cmdlet or use "Start PowerShell.exe" from the File menu.
To view/modify the list of blocked console applications, use $psUnsupportedConsoleApplications, or consult online help.
```

Other commands, like mySQL, will just hang indefinitely, since the ISE cannot properly handle user input to the application. You can read more about this limitation here:
[PowerShell Team blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I see there is no way to do that as of now.